# ファイルの上書きができない。

Tags: python

```
with open('sil01python.csv', 'r',encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    t = ''
    for line in f:
        t += line.replace("<br"," ")

    with open('sil01python.csv','w',encoding='utf-8') as writing:
        writing.write(t)
```

以下のエラーが出ました。

```
C:\Users\Yo\Desktop\excel>python python.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open('sil01python.csv','w',encoding='utf-8') as writing:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'sil01python.csv'
```

Comment: `sil01python.csv` ファイルが read only(読み取り専用)になっていませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

単純に、`write`のための`open`がインデントしていて、`read`の`open`の延長で動作しているからです。
両方を同じインデントにすれば`write`の`open`は出来ます。
つまり`read`の`open`は終わらせる必要があります。

```
with open('sil01python.csv', 'r',encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    t = ''
    for line in f:
        t += line.replace("<br"," ")

with open('sil01python.csv','w',encoding='utf-8') as writing:
    writing.write(t)
```